# Database Connection From Session in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I have multiple database connection, but for perusahaan db connection I want set database_name from session. how to resolve it?

.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
config(['database.connections.perusahaan.database' => session('db_key')]);
```

You set a config variable runtime with the `config` helper by passing a value to it from the `session` helper. The way you do it fails, because session is not yet available while reading config.

I would like to add a warning that you might trust data that should not be trusted, however I do not know enough about your app to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that at runtime, it cannot be done directly from the configuration file.

```
config(['database.connections.perusahaan.database' => session('db_key')]);
```

You may also need to purge the connection as it may be cached

```
app(DatabaseManager::class)->purge('perusahaan');
```